# WCF error related to ContentType

Tags: .net, wcf

I have hosted a WCF service ( Visual Studio 2010) it works fine from test app and soapUI. The application consuming the wcf Service is getting Error :  415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

I tried  follwoing but did not work [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

as an attribute to the class service.
 In addition add this line to the web.config:

Comment: you forgot to add the text for the line you added to the web config :o). Also, could you add some more detail, for example your service and client config and some description of the service code...

Answer (score 0):

This probably is because of a mismatch of the bindings, just as the error message says. For instance, the server may be using WSHttpBinding, and the client BasicHttpBinding.

This happened to me just a few days ago. I have a unit test that I was running against both the QA and Development servers. They're running different versions of the service - with different bindings. I had to adjust the unit test depending on which server I was testing, otherwise I got that exact error.

Comment: I changed to wsHttpBinding but did not work originally it was basichttpbinding

Comment: Try starting the service, then go to the client and do "Update Service Reference". Then rebuild the client and try again.

Comment: Do you mean wshttpbinding should work for Above error ( I think client is sending contenttype 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

Comment: with wshttpbinding now contentType changed to 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. but client is sending 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Ok, this is a web post binding, which I've never used. But look at webHttpBinding.